# Storing a reference integer and it's value

Tags: c#, list

I want to store a variable length list which will contain a reference integer id which will be taken from a database so there could be many or few and with each of them I want an integer ranking number. So for instance I will have a reference integer 14 with a rating/ranking of 58. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since each integer can, I assume, only occur once, a `Dictionary<int, int>` sounds like the best solution.

```
var rankings = new Dictionary<int, int>();
int someInt = GetIntFromDB();
int someRanking = GetRankingForInt(someInt);

rankings[someInt] = someRanking;
```

Comment: What I'm doing is I am going through each column in the DB and getting the id of the rows which value in the column is the same as the one searched. Each column has a different weight, so I am searching through each column and when the value is the same as the one search I am adding weight value to the id. I will only take the id of the matches though, not all the ids. Is this method still the best for this approach?